# Is there an easy way to grant yourself oauth access?

Tags: oauth

Every so often I hack up my own projects to solve my own problems. Sometimes I want to use data from a service. This access is often provided by oauth.

oAuth solves a more general problem than I want to solve. It lets a programmer request that a user provides data via a website. In my case I am the user and the programmer, and I don't really want to implement the website.

Is there an easy way for me to grant myself access to my own data without writing a website?

## Resources

[This diagram](https://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=dGl0bGUgQXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbiBDb2RlIEdyYW50IEZsb3cKCnBhcnRpY2lwYW50ICJSZXNvdXJjZSBPd25lciIgYXMgUk8AFQ5DbGllbnQAFgVDAC8OAFsOU2VydgA8B0FTAE8XABkLUlMKCkMtPitBUzoAgR4UUmVxdWVzdApub3RlIG92ZXIgQVM6IE5lZWRzIGMAgQ0FX2lkLCByZWRpcmVjdF91cmksXG5yZXNwb25zZV90eXBlPWNvZGVbLCBzY29wZSwgc3RhdGVdClJPLT5BUzogTG9naW4gJiBDb25zZW50CkFTLS0-Pi1DAHcXAFIGAIEpCUV4Y2hhbmdlAIJZBmZvciBBY2Nlc3MgVG9rZW4AgRYgAIE6B3NlY3JldACBNBFncmFudACBPAZhAIM_DF9jb2RlLCBjb2RlAIEiDABtCyBbKyBSZWZyZXNoAIEDBl0KbG9vcACCYwVSUzogQ2FsbCBBUEkgd2l0aACBJA5SAIF2CQCBZAgAHwZEYXRhCmVuZA&s=qsdhttp://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2) from this  blog post [http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/] gives a good overview of oauth.

Comment: Oauth defines authentication server, resource server and client app. Now in your case what is the programmer? And user?

Comment: @OhadR Using the terminology of ouath, I am the client and the resource owner. Google is the authentication serer and the resource server.  I want to grant myself access to my own data, and access it through google programmatically.

Comment: So rather than using authorization code grant type, you may use implicit grant type which is much simpler

Comment: So with an implicit grant I can get a single credential with which I can access my own data directly from google?

Answer (score 1):

Only if I understand your flow correctly, I think you should use the **password grant type** ([see here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)).

Because you use google authentication server (google account) and resource server (e.g. gmail). You use the client app (maybe you write it yourself) so you sign in with username and password, so Password is your preferred grant type.

In this flow:

1. The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access token.
2. The user’s password is accessible to the application!
3. Should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application)
4. It is used for only highly-trusted clients, such as a mobile application written by the resource-server.

Comment: "The credentials should only be used when there is a high
   degree of trust between the resource owner and the client" Do I trust myself :grin:

Comment: This is why I think it is the most appropriate grant type :-) Im glad it helped

Comment: feel free to mark this answer as 'accepted', if it is...

Comment: Will do. I was having a look at seeing if I can giv myself this grant ofrom google...

Comment: Google may not support this... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 So in your use case I think the best match is "Client-side (JavaScript) applications"